# TypingError in Numba 0.37

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, jit, numba

I'm trying to optimize a Python code for the calculation of the following formula :
[image: erez_photo]

where phi is a 2D array, and phi_i is a 1D array. 
I've build a code for it, and tried to use the jit decorator, but it gives me TypingError. This is the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def calcAlpha(phi,fix_phis):
    phi_sq = phi**2
    fix_phis_sq = fix_phis**2
    F = []
    for l,phi_l_sq in enumerate(fix_phis_sq):
        F.append(2.0*phi_sq/(phi_sq-phi_l_sq))
#        print F[l]
        for j,phi_j_sq in enumerate(fix_phis_sq):
            if j != l:
                F[l]*=(phi_sq - phi_j_sq)/(phi_l_sq + phi_j_sq)
                F[l]*=(phi_l_sq + phi_j_sq)/(phi_sq + phi_j_sq)
    return np.array(F)
fix_sigmas=np.linspace(0.1,1,8)
sigma = np.random.random((252,252))
```

Trying to run the function give the following message:

```
In [7]: fout=calcAlpha(sigma,fix_sigmas)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-88b11ed9cd73> in <module>()
----> 1 fout=calcAlpha(sigma,fix_sigmas)

../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.pyc in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    328                                 for i, err in failed_args))
    329                 e.patch_message(msg)
--> 330             raise e
    331 
    332     def inspect_llvm(self, signature=None):

TypingError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()
  File "../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 454, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 881, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 846, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
TypingError: Invalid usage of Function(<built-in function array>) with parameters (list(array(float64, 2d, C)))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypingError: array(float64, 2d, C) not allowed in a homogenous sequence
...

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Invalid usage of Function(<built-in function array>) with parameters (list(array(float64, 2d, C)))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypingError: array(float64, 2d, C) not allowed in a homogenous sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

Append arrays to lists isn't supported and if supported in the future not recommendable if it can be avoided.
Also writing out all loops is recommendable for best performance using Numba.

**Example**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calcAlpha(phi,fix_phis):
    phi_sq = phi*phi
    fix_phis_sq = fix_phis*fix_phis #1d
    F = np.zeros((fix_phis_sq.shape[0],phi.shape[0],phi.shape[1]),dtype=phi.dtype)

    for l in nb.prange(fix_phis_sq.shape[0]):
        for x in range(phi_sq.shape[0]):
          for y in range(phi_sq.shape[1]):
            F[l,x,y]=2.0*phi_sq[x,y]/(phi_sq[x,y]-fix_phis_sq[l])

        #if fix_phis doesn't get bigger, but phi does parallelize this loop
        for j in range(fix_phis_sq.shape[0]):
            if j != l:
                for x in range(phi_sq.shape[0]):
                    for y in range(phi_sq.shape[1]):
                        F[l,x,y]*=(phi_sq[x,y] - fix_phis_sq[j])/(fix_phis_sq[l] + fix_phis_sq[j])
                        F[l,x,y]*=(fix_phis_sq[l] + fix_phis_sq[j])/(phi_sq[x,y] + fix_phis_sq[j])
    return F
```

Most of the speedup (7x on my Quadcore-i7) comes from parallelization.

Comment: Thanks, will try it..I tried to find what is the difference between jit and njit but couldn't find a clear explanation - could you say a word on this?

Comment: njit is a shortcut for jit(nopython=True). If using jit with no arguments or nopython=False there may be interactions with the Python interpreter (eg. append an array to a list), with jit(nopython=True) or njit it throws an error if a Python call is necessary (like you experienced)